# Hash syntax strangeness

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any difference between the `:key =&gt; &ldquo;value&rdquo;` and `key: &ldquo;value&rdquo;` hash notations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no)

What's the difference between this:

```
method: :delete
```

and this?

```
:method => :delete
```

I'm guessing it has to do with different versions of Rails but not sure. I have only worked in Rails 3.x.

Comment: well i sorta inferred that much but curious why have two different ways...? one seems like a json-like 'method: :delete and :method => :delete seems more railsy. have both of these syntaxes been available across all rails versions?

Comment: Doesn't have to do a lot with Rails. It's plain Ruby. The hash-rocket notation is there since ever. The colon syntax was introduced with Ruby 1.9.

Comment: @kurtybot sorry, I didn't realize you had already inferred that

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563766/hash-syntax-in-ruby
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220195/allowing-for-ruby-1-9s-hash-syntax
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412242/what-are-the-benefits-of-the-new-hash-syntax-in-ruby-1-9
http://logicalfriday.com/2011/06/20/i-dont-like-the-ruby-1-9-hash-syntax/

Comment: +1 @Abram. Andrew Marshall, i had a feeling it would be a duplicate thread but it's not a super search friendly topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are completely equivalent, except the first can only be used since ruby 1.9 (and higher, of course).

In ruby 1.8 the hash syntax used the `=>`, also known as the `hash rocket`. You could put anything in front, and anything behind, but the thing in front is your key, behind the value. If you have a symbol as key, and a symbol as value, you would write:

```
:method => :delete
```

But you could also write

```
{ 1 => 'one', :2 => 'two', 'THREE' => 3 }
```

Now, for ruby 1.9.x, a new shorter syntax was introduced. Since most people use symbols as keys, you can now write:

```
method: :delete
```

Which is just a shorter/cleaner version. Also note that it is possible to mix both styles, which in some cases is needed.

E.g. in ruby 1.8 you would write:

```
{ :class => 'smthg', :'data-type' => 'a type' }
```

This would translate to the following in ruby 1.9

```
{ class: 'smthg', :'data-type' => 'a type' }
```

Note that you can still keep using the "old" hash syntax as well. It is a matter of preference. Personally for hashes with only symbols as keys, I use the clean/short version. I generally try not to mix hash-style in a single hash :)